# How to deal with the standard error of fixed-effect in lmer using r?

Tags: r, time-series, lme4-nlme, difference-in-difference

I have a time series data across different locations with pre-post indicator. Also there are some locations belong to one intervention group and some other belong to a different intervention group. I am using `lmer` with random intercept and some fixed effects. Here is the code,

```
model_alcohol <- lmer(Sales_per_capita ~ Time + sin(2*pi*Time/6)+cos(2*pi*Time/6) + policy + Covid+ policy:Covid + (1|Geography), data = alcohol_all, na.action = na.omit)
```

Note that I use `sin(2*pi*Time/6)` and `cos(2*pi*Time/6)` to adjust for seasonality. The interaction terms here is the difference-in-difference coefficient, is my main interest. Here is the fitted coefficients for fixed effects,

[image: Output]

I concern that some of the fixed-effects have a very high standard error (e.g. interaction term has standard error 4.74), because I am going to interpret the coefficients. Is there any way I can fix the issue? I found a post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/49014/how-to-deal-with-correlated-fixed-effects-in-a-mixed-effects-model) asking about the correlations among the coefficients.

Comment: Welcome. The standard errors associated with the “fixed effects” are inflated/deflated? Please clarify.

Comment: @ThomasBilach: Sorry I don't understand what you meant by inflated/deflated. Could you please clarify?

Comment: You write: “...some of the fixed-effects have a very standard error, because I am going to interpret the coefficients.” A very what?

Comment: @ThomasBilach: Sorry, I have edited the post. I meant some of the standard error seems high.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnitudes of the standard errors of the coefficients don't matter in and of themselves. What matters is the ratio of the coefficient value to that standard error, which is the t-value and the basis for your significance test. That interaction term is significant by the standard p < 0.05 criterion so you certainly can try to interpret it.

Think about it this way: if you measured a set of distances in millimeters and then the same distances in miles, the magnitude of the standard error of the mean distance expressed in the millimeter scale would seem to be much greater than the magnitude of the standard error expressed in miles. But the relative error would be the same in both scales.

Finally, it's not surprising that an interaction term will be correlated with the corresponding individual terms that go into it: it's just their product even if you don't directly think of the interaction that way.

Comment: Thanks so much for clarifying. It makes sense.